# Use traditional post, Ajax post or Channel API for my own Like button?

Tags: ajax, google-app-engine, websocket

I'm developing a mobile app with 40 million users per day.

The app will show articles to the user that they can choose to read, no image, just plain text. The user can pull to refresh to get new articles.

I would like to implement the like button to each individual article (my own like button not Facebook). Assume that each client click 100 like per person per day it will be equal to 40M x 100 = 4000 M time of data transfer.

I'm a newbie with no experience with big project before. What is the best approach that suit my project. I found Google Channel API is 0.0001 dollars per channel created which is 80M x 0.0001 = 8000 USD per day (assume there are 2 connection per person) which is quite expensive. Or there is other way to do this? ex. Ajax or Traditional post. My app don't need real-time. which one is less resource consumption? Can someone please guide me. I really need help.

I'm plan to use google app engine for this project.

Answer (score 1):

A small difference in efficiency would multiply to a significant change in operational costs at those volumes.  I would not blindly trust theoretical claims made by documentation.  It would be sensible to build and test each alternative design and ensure it is compatible with the rest of your software.  A few days of trials with several thousand simulated users will produce valuable results at a bearable cost.

Channels, Ajax and conventional web requests are all feasible at the conceptual level of your question.  Add in some monitoring code and compare the results of load tests at various levels of scale.  In addition to performance and cost, the instrumentation code should also monitor reliability.

Comment: Can traditional post done without refreshing the page? Or I need Other technology ex. Ajax? Because refresh the page is inefficient.

Comment: Traditional post refreshes the page.  In addition to being inefficient a browser window might flicker visibly.  Improved alternative designs such as [jQuery Mobile](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/) do use Ajax to offer a Single Page Application model (another [example](http://addyosmani.com/blog/building-spas-jquerys-best-friends/)).

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt your app will get 40 million users a day, and doubt even more that each of those will click Like ten times a day.

But I don't understand why clicking Like would result in a lot of data transfer. It's a simple Ajax request, which wouldn't even need to return anything than an empty response, with a 200 code for success and a 400 for failure.

Comment: I'm very sure it will. I just hide the real cool concept behind it ^^ what about if it reach 40 M user? The direction of using Ajax for like button is the suitable tool?

Answer (score 0):

I would experiment with different options on a small scale first, to get some data from which you can extrapolate to calculate your costs.  However, a simple ajax request with a lightweight handler is likely to be cheaper than Channel API.

If you are getting 40m daily users, reading at least 100 articles, then making 100 likes, I'm guessing you will have something exceeding 8bn requests a day.  On that basis, your instance costs are likely to be significant before even considering a like button.  At that volume of requests, how you handle the request on the server side will be important in managing your costs.

Using tools like AppStats, Chrome Dev Tools and Apache Jmeter will help you get a better view on your response times, instance & bandwidth costs and user experience before you scale up.